# Android Spinner How to not show specific selections

Tags: android

I have a spinner in a toolbar, I also have replaced the toolbar with an icon and when the user selects the first option and the last option in the spinner I do not want it to show, or in other words do not want to replace the Spinner with text but the rest for the rest between the first and last option. I want them to show. How can I do this?

```
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView,
                                   View view, int i, long l) {
            int total = adapterView.getCount();
            if(i == 0){

            }
            else if(i == total -1){

            }
```

Comment: Please explain further.

Comment: In the closed state, the `Spinner` shows the current selection. There is no notion of the `Spinner` showing something other than the current selection. With a suitable `SpinnerAdapter`, you might be able to fake it, but it is unclear what you want to have appear other than the current selection when the user selects the first or last option.

Answer (score 1):

```
// declare it inside class
private int prev_pos=0; // initially it zero, you can set your desire position 

if(i =! 0 && i!= adapterView.getCount()-1 )
{
  // do what you want
  prev_pos=i; // store the previous position if it's not last or first
}
else{
 // display previous position 
 yourSpinnerObject.setSelection(prev_pos);
}
```